# In a Twig template, how can I group items in an array by the value of a property of an item?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In PHP I would do this:

```
$menu_groups = array();
foreach($items as $item){
    $menu_id = $item['properties.menu_id'];
    
    if(!array_key_exists($menu_id, $menu_groups)) $menu_groups[$menu_id] = array();
    
    $menu_groups[$menu_id][] = $item;
}
```

How can I accomplish something similar in a Twig template?

Comment: Do it with PHP: templates shouldn't contain the logic. Note that `if(!array_key_exists....` is not needed, so you can also remove the  *$menu_id* variable.

Comment: @Pippo If I could do it in PHP I would have. Thanks for the tip about the $menu_id variable tho.

Answer (score 2):

as @pippo said in the comment templates should not contain the logic for better  maitainability and testability and also for good practice of Symfony framework with twig as template engine. but if you insisted on knowing how you can do it I tried to transform your code from PHP to Twig and it should maybe look something like

```
{% set menu_groups = items|group('properties.menu_id') %}
{% for menu_id, items in menu_groups %}
    <h2>MyMenuID : {{ menu_id }}</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for item in items %}
            <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

if your group filter is not defined in your twig then maybe try to create one

1. First yo go to your src/Twig.
2. Create a new class that extends Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension (check doc here [click](https://symfony.com/doc/5.2/templating/twig_extension.html))
3. Don't forget to declare your filter class in config/services.yaml

then your new filter class should be like

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return [
       new TwigFilter('group', [$this, 'groupArrayItemsBy']),
     ];
 }

public function groupArrayItemsBy(array $array, string $property)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $key = $item[$property];
        if (!isset($result[$key])) {
           $result[$key] = [];
        }
        $result[$key][] = $item;
    }
    return $result;
}
```